# Mongoose : How to Find and Count document at the same time

Tags: node.js, mongoose

What is the correct way to find and count documents at the same time with a filter?

My filter property is an email passed down via req.params.email like so :

```
exports.getTotalInventory =  asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
email= req.params.email
  Inventory.countDocuments({email:email},(err, inventory)=>{
  if(err){
  res.status(500);
  res.send(err);
  } else {
  res.json(inventory);
  }
  });
  });
```

I know my mistake may be too obvious but I will be glad if anyone can show me what am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find documents and process them just use `Inventory.find` and use `.length` property to get the count of items.

```
Inventory.find({email:email}, (err, inventory) => {
  if(err){
     res.status(500);
     res.send(err);
  } else {
     res.json({items: inventory, count: inventory.length});
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response... I just tried it, but got an empty array [ ]

Comment: @8SINS Please check and make sure there are `documents` in the `inventory` collection that matches the provided `email`.

Comment: @Mehmet I am so sorry! I forgot to define the email that I passed into the function. I forgot to do this ==> const email=req.params.email

Answer (score 2):

`countDocuments` will count your entire Inventory collection.

```
const doc = Inventory.find({email:email});
const count = Inventory.countDocuments({email:email});// closing parenthesis
const response = await Promise.all([doc, count]);
res.json({items: response[0], count: response[1]});
```

or if your want to count base on found documents:

```
const response = await Inventory.find({email:email};
res.json({items: response, count: response.length});// length
```

Comment: Your solution is logically correct and should work, but while testing with Postman, I got an empty array [ ]

Comment: Sorry! I found the mistake, your code works perfectly